# obtener actividades solamente de los usuarios de mi oficina

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada "actividades", dónde se almacenan todo lo que hacen los usuarios relacionado a los pedidos, "crear una nota", "crear una visita"... etc

Esa tabla tiene el campo "usuario_id", que es una foreign key que apunta directamente al id del usuario, y demás campos con la información de lo que hacen...

*La cosa es que me gustaría mostrar todas las actividades, que hayan tenido fecha de modificación de hoy, y que solamente vea los usuarios de mi oficina (también hay una tabla de oficinas, con el id y el nombre de cada oficina )*

- Actualmente puedo obtener los usuarios que me interesan, que deben ser con x permisos y activos code:

  ```
    $usuarios_oficina = Usuario::where("oficina_id", Auth::user()->oficina_id)
    ->where("usuariotype", "=", "Asesor")
    ->where("estado", "Activo")
    ->get();
  ```
- Aquí obtengo todas las actividades que han sido creadas, modificadas o cerradas hoy, mediante el campo "modified_at", que se actualiza con las 3 acciones, code:

  ```
   $actividades_all = ActividadesPedido::whereDate('updated_at', Carbon::today())->get();
  ```
- El problema empieza aquí, por que yo quiero mostrar las actividades, que hayan sido modificadas a día de hoy, **pero solo en mis usuarios *$usuarios_oficina***

*Mis intentos de soluciones sin éxito:*

- He probado a filtrar la colección de eloquent de actividades mediante el **"->filter"**, pero me ha devuelto una colección vacia, code, postdata: hay actividades con esos usuarios actualizadas a día de hoy, lo he comprobado previamente en la bbdd.. pero esto devuelve un collection vacío

  ```
   $actividades = $actividades_all->filter(function($actividad){
        // vuelvo a declarar la variable, por que si no, me la marca como si no existe, a pesar de estar declarada fuera.
        $usuarios_oficina = Usuario::where("oficina_id", Auth::user()->oficina_id)
        ->where("usuariotype", "=", "Asesor")
        ->where("estado", "Activo")
        ->orderBy("updated_at","asc")
        ->get(); 

        foreach($usuarios_oficina as $usuario){
            // Teorícamente debería devolver el resultado, cúando la $actividad->usuario_id sea igual al id del usuario
            return $actividad->usuario_id == $usuario->id;
        }
    });
  ```
- También he probado con una forma un poco "menos ortodoxa", mediante bucles for-each, pero no me ha devuelto nada tampoco, code:

  ```
   $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

   foreach($usuarios_oficina as $usuario){

   foreach($usuario->actividades as $actividad){
    if($actividad->created_at == $today){
        echo "> ".$usuario->nombre." ha hecho la actividad ".$actividad->tipo_actividad." ".$actividad->updated_at."<br>";
        }
    }
   }
  ```

*RESUMEN*

Sólamente quiero listar todas las actividades , ordenadas por "updated_at" de forma descendiente, y que sólamente me muestre las que $usuarios_oficina hayan hecho, pero es que me esta costando de más, a pesar que tengo el pensamiento que debería ser más facil , y que seguro que con algún metodo de Eloquent se debería hacer, gracias y buena tarde!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obten los id de los usuarios con `pluck` y filtralos en la consulta

```
$usuarios_oficina = Usuario::select('id')->where("oficina_id", Auth::user()->oficina_id)
  ->where("usuariotype", "Asesor")
  ->where("estado", "Activo")
  ->get()->pluck('id');

//Introduce los usuarios en whereIn
$actividades_all = ActividadesPedido::whereIn('usuario_id', $usuarios_oficina)->whereDate('updated_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Comment: Genial funciona, pero en caso de que quiera hacer un join con otra tabla de actividades, cómo debería hacerlo? Con este método no lo estoy consiguiendo @jonathan-orta